# Can't add an application to the "Open with other Application" menu

Tags: 22.04, arduino

So I installed the Arduino IDE via flatpak and it works fine. But every time I want to open a .ino file I have to open a window and select open and search the file. I already searched options for adding the application to the "open with" menu that I can just click the file and it gets opened but it doesn't work. The method was to add a .desktop file which I did, here is its content:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=2.0
Type=Application
Name=Arduino IDE
Icon=/home/kerem/.icons/kora/apps/scalable/arduino.svg
Categories=Utility
Exec=/var/lib/flatpak/app/cc.arduino.IDE2/x86_64/stable/99e71b2b085273ee56ccbca19e88f72d47851c15a0b0c669614e
0813b58b150b/files/arduino-ide/arduino-ide %u
```

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: So is the "open with" completely not working or are you at least able to open the file using the ide after searching for it? The reason I ask is because you should be able to right click on the `.ino` file and then select the **"Properties"** menu (instead of "open with") and then from there, you can select your open with application to **"set as default"**. Therefore, if the problem is that you need to search for the IDE file each time using the "open with" menu, then using the "Properties" menu should allow you to permanently set the IDE as the default.

Comment: the problem is that the IDE is not available in the "open with" menu. With the .desktop file i tried to add the application to the menu but it still does not show up. I can only open the app within the Application from its menu with "file" > "open" and then search the .ino file location

Comment: Where does your desktop launcher reside on your file system?

Comment: it resides on the path that I typed in for Exec=.... So it's the correct path to the executable